# Custom Printing Service with Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, printing, data-driven-pages, geoprocessing-service

I've been tasked with creating a custom web app hosted in ArcGIS Online that has the ability to export out data driven pages through a printing service (we also have ArcGIS Server).  Within the printing widget, I noticed you can point to a printing service.

What we want to be able to do is have any user query features, go through the printing widget and have it export out a multi-page PDF of all features that are queried.  I am familiar with sharing the "Get Layout Templates Info" as a geoprocessing service but I'm running into a bit of trouble with the data driven pages aspect.

Comment: Have you come up with any solution?